# If $A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing$, is one $A \cap B$, $B \cap C$ or $C \cap A$ empty too?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I give counter example to this?

Prove or find a counter example to the following claim:

> For all sets $A$, $B$, $C$ if $A\cap B\cap C=\varnothing$, then either $A\cap B=\varnothing$ or $A\cap C=\varnothing$ or $B\cap C=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have the sets $A = \{ a,b,c \}, B = \{ a,d,e \}, C = \{ f, b, e \}$

$A \cap B = \{ a \}$

$A \cap C = \{ b \}$

$B \cap C = \{ e \}$

But

$A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing$

because $a,b,e$ are not in all 3

It is clear that if there is at least $1$ common element between any $2$ sets then the intersection of any $2$ sets will be the common elements. If none of these elements are common between all of the sets then the intersection of all of them is the null set.

Answer (score 7):

This claim is clearly false: it means that if three set have no common element, a pair of them have no common element.

Counter-example: $\,A=\{1,2\},\enspace B=\{2,3\},\enspace C=\{3,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{2,3,4\}$, $C = \{1,5,6\}$. Then $A\cap B\cap C = \varnothing$, but $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$, $B\cap C\neq\varnothing$ and $C\cap A\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: The intersection of A and C is empty in your example. Also please sur mathmod to write your answer.
EDIT : It is correct now.

Comment: you right i corrected it